# Debug IIS 8 with Visual Studio 2012. Insufficient Permissions

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, iis-8

If I try to start debugging an ASP.Net MVC (3 or 4, doesn't matter) using a local IIS 8 it says (just clicking play button):

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. Visual Studio has
>   insufficient privileges to        debug this process. To debug this
>   process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.

If I try to attach manually with DEBUG -> Attach To Process -> Show Process From all Users -> w3wp.exe I get a simmilar message.

> Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio has insufficient
>   privileges to debug this process.      To debug this process, Visual
>   Studio must be run as an administrator.

Using IIS Express it works, just the full IIS 8 is stopping me from debugging.

I've enabled Debugging on IIS -> Default Web Site -> .Net Compilation -> Debug = True

I've also tried changing the DefaultAppPool to use ApplicationPoolIdentity / Network Service / My own Account.

And, of couse, I've tried to run VS2012 as administrator.

Comment: I've tried now with the my local account and it works, but not with domain one. I'm a Domain Administrator so I don't know why this should be a problema.

Comment: I have the same problem here but I'm not on a Domain

Comment: Ok I got it working, I installed VSCommands 11 so it'S always open in Administrator mode but I checked the Start with Medium Integrity Level so I could'not debug it.

Comment: Hey I also have VS Commands installed. What you mean by medium integrity level. UAC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VinnyG was right. Is a VSCommands problem. Checking Medium Trust on VSCommands disables IIS debug. [image]